# Docker container stopping in the Jelastic environment

Tags: docker, jelastic

When stopping a Docker container in native Docker environment, by default it sends the SIGTERM signal to the container's init process (PID 1) which should be the actual application, which should then handle the shutdown properly. However when running container in the Jelastic, this does not seem to be case, and instead of gracefully terminating the SQL server, it seems that the server crashes every time.

I did try writing and enabling a Systemd service that gets the SQL PID and then send SIGTERM to it, but it doesn't seem to run, and judging from the logs there's no service shutdown messages at all, just startup messages.

So what changes would be required to the container or the environment to get the server to get the SIGTERM signal and have enough time, maybe few seconds, to do the graceful shutdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thank you for reporting the issue, we tried to reproduce the problem on our test lab and were able to get exactly same result. We agree that issue is really serious so we are going to fix it with highest priority now. Please accept our apologies for that inconvenience. I want to notice that due to our primary design we also expect the process to be terminated first with "sigterm" signal and only after not receiving a termination result for some period of time the system had to send "sigkill", only after considering that process cannot be terminated gracefully. Our engineers will work on this to explore the issue deeper and will deliver a fix shortly.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, it seems to be fixed in our provider version now at least. so marking this answered.